# Pythonでクリック音を流しながら録音したいのですが．

Tags: python

Pythonでテンポを設定し，1小節の長さ（時間）に正確に録音したいです．
その際，バックグラウンドでクリック音を流しながら録音したいのですが，
どうしたらよいのでしょうか．

Comment: いまはどのように音を流してらっしゃるのでしょうか（ライブラリ等）。また、このご質問はメインの音声とリズムの音声の2つの音を同時に流したいということでしょうか？　質問文をもう少し具体的に書いていただけると、回答しやすくなりそうです（「編集」から自由に追記できます）。

Comment: Pythonでやる必要は？というのもありますね。既存のDAWソフトに機能があるようですし。[リアルタイム入力をしてみよう：その１](https://kaymusic-online.com/index.php?sonar_realtime1), [Ableton Liveを使った、スタジオ＆ライブ用の同期設定](https://lostmortal.info/2013/11/ableton-live-9-intro.html), [BPMを測定して、曲のテンポを知る](https://utattemita.jp/bpm-tempo/), [フリーのDAW、Tracktion 7を使ってみよう - 5　～クリックトラック・テイク録音～](http://fez.ya-gasuri.com/tracktion/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%86%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E9%8C%B2%E9%9F%B3)